# How can I use the :has() selector to add animation to preview sibling when hovering over a specific element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a code with three article cards, each containing an image and description. When I hover over a specific card, I want to blur the preview and the next card sibling.

I tried using the `~` selector, but it only selects the next sibling.

```css
.articles>*:hover ~ * {
    filter: blur(1px);
}
```

Then, I tried using the `:has()` selector to select the preview sibling, but it didn't work.

Maybe i do something wrong?

```css
.articles>*:hover:has(~ .articles>*) {
    filter: blur(1px);
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@400;800&display=swap");
body {
  font-family: "Work sans", Arial, Monospace, sans-serif;
  background-color: #282a3a;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: clamp(1.13rem, calc(0.86rem + 1.05vw), 1.65rem);
  margin-block: 1rem;
  color: #10cab7;
}

p {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: calc(1rem + 1px);
  color: #829299;
}

.articles {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  padding: 4rem;
  gap: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.articles>* {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background-color: #181823;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.306);
}

.articles>*:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.306);
  transform: scale(1.03);
}


/* add blur to all next sibling article cards when you hover over on a specific card */

.articles>*:hover~* {
  filter: blur(1px);
}


/* add blur to all preview sibling article cards when you hover over on a specific card */

.articles>*:hover:has(~.articles>*) {
  filter: blur(1px);
}

.articles img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-image: linear-gradient( to left, rgb(5, 60, 64), rgb(0, 255, 157)) 27 / 35px;
  -moz-border-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(5, 60, 64), rgb(0, 255, 157)) 27 / 35px;
  -ms-border-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(5, 60, 64), rgb(0, 255, 157)) 27 / 35px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(5, 60, 64), rgb(0, 255, 157)) 27 / 35px;
  border-image-width: 0px 0px 4px auto;
}

.articles .article-desc {
  padding: 2rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="articles bkg-gray">

  <div class="article-1">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/nzK9N7l.png" alt="services">

    <div class="article-desc">
      <h3>
        Graphic Design
      </h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Officia, velit? Inventore voluptas quis eveniet expedita numquam pariatur tempora.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="article-2">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5EOzUIQ.png">

    <div class="article-desc">
      <h3>
        Graphic Design
      </h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Officia, velit? Inventore voluptas quis eveniet expedita numquam pariatur tempora.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="article-3">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/7cnLyBD.png" alt="services">
    <div class="article-desc">
      <h3>
        Graphic Design
      </h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Officia, velit? Inventore voluptas quis eveniet expedita numquam pariatur tempor.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean preview or is it 'previous'? ie do you want to blur just the one before and the one after, or do you want to blur all but the one that is being hovered?

Comment: i want to blur all but the one that is being hovered, (all cards  before and after the hovered one)

Answer (score 2):

You could use this CSS:

```
.articles:hover > *:not(:hover) {
    filter: blur(1px);
}
```

When you enter `.articles` with your mouse it will blur all the articles, but the one you're hovering over. It will unfortunately also blur all the articles when you're hovering on a gap between two.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@400;800&display=swap");
body {
  font-family: "Work sans", Arial, Monospace, sans-serif;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: clamp(1.13rem, calc(0.86rem + 1.05vw), 1.65rem);
  margin-block: 1rem;
  color: #10cab7;
}

p {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: calc(1rem + 1px);
  color: #2c4755;
}

.articles {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  padding: 4rem;
  gap: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.articles>* {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.306);
}

.articles>*:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.306);
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

.articles:hover > *:not(:hover) {
  filter: blur(1px);
}

.articles img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-image: linear-gradient( to left, rgb(5, 60, 64), rgb(0, 255, 157)) 27 / 35px;
  -moz-border-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(5, 60, 64), rgb(0, 255, 157)) 27 / 35px;
  -ms-border-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(5, 60, 64), rgb(0, 255, 157)) 27 / 35px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(5, 60, 64), rgb(0, 255, 157)) 27 / 35px;
  border-image-width: 0px 0px 4px auto;
}

.articles .article-desc {
  padding: 2rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="articles bkg-gray">

  <div class="article-1">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/nzK9N7l.png" alt="services">

    <div class="article-desc">
      <h3>
        Graphic Design
      </h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Officia, velit? Inventore voluptas quis eveniet expedita numquam pariatur tempora.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="article-2">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5EOzUIQ.png">

    <div class="article-desc">
      <h3>
        Graphic Design
      </h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Officia, velit? Inventore voluptas quis eveniet expedita numquam pariatur tempora.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="article-3">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/7cnLyBD.png" alt="services">
    <div class="article-desc">
      <h3>
        Graphic Design
      </h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Officia, velit? Inventore voluptas quis eveniet expedita numquam pariatur tempor.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Douwe de Haan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336174/douwe-de-haan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75947060/2817442) and replacing `padding` with `margin` with the `pointer-events` applied correctly, it entirely works as wished.

The `pointer-events: none` on the `.articles` (which is the container) disables the "hover" entirely, and the `pointer-events: all` on the `.articles>*` (children (the cards)) enables it, so the blurring will take effect only when you are hovering on the cards, not outside of them (all).

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@400;800&display=swap");
body {
  font-family: "Work sans", Arial, Monospace, sans-serif;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: clamp(1.13rem, calc(0.86rem + 1.05vw), 1.65rem);
  margin-block: 1rem;
  color: #10cab7;
}

p {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: calc(1rem + 1px);
  color: #2c4755;
}

.articles {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  margin: 4rem;
  gap: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.articles>* {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.306);
  pointer-events: all;
}

.articles>*:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.306);
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

.articles:hover>*:not(:hover) {
  filter: blur(1px);
}

.articles img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-image: linear-gradient( to left, rgb(5, 60, 64), rgb(0, 255, 157)) 27 / 35px;
  -moz-border-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(5, 60, 64), rgb(0, 255, 157)) 27 / 35px;
  -ms-border-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(5, 60, 64), rgb(0, 255, 157)) 27 / 35px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(5, 60, 64), rgb(0, 255, 157)) 27 / 35px;
  border-image-width: 0px 0px 4px auto;
}

.articles .article-desc {
  padding: 2rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="articles bkg-gray">

  <div class="article-1">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/nzK9N7l.png" alt="services">

    <div class="article-desc">
      <h3>
        Graphic Design
      </h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Officia, velit? Inventore voluptas quis eveniet expedita numquam pariatur tempora.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="article-2">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5EOzUIQ.png">

    <div class="article-desc">
      <h3>
        Graphic Design
      </h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Officia, velit? Inventore voluptas quis eveniet expedita numquam pariatur tempora.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="article-3">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/7cnLyBD.png" alt="services">
    <div class="article-desc">
      <h3>
        Graphic Design
      </h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Officia, velit? Inventore voluptas quis eveniet expedita numquam pariatur tempor.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain how `pointer-events` works here?

Comment: Sure. The `pointer-events: none` on the `.articles` (which is the container) disables the "hover" entirely, and the `pointer-events: all` on `the .articles>*` (children) enables it, so the blurring will take effect only when you are hovering on the cards, not outside of them (all).